# How to calculate the indefinite integral of softmax function by sympy package?

Tags: python, sympy

How to calculate the indefinite integral of softmax?

`softmax(s) = exp(s_i) \ [sum_k exp(s_k)]`, in which s is a vector.

I know the `sympy` can calculate the indefinite integral for a function which is used to a scaler. However, the softmax is a function used to a vector.

I expect an example by using python code, `sympy` package is better.